# Flutter how to empty array

Tags: flutter

Flutter i am adding data by forEach loop in an array

Code.

```
class _BrowserCategoryPage2State extends State<BrowserCategoryPage2> {
  var items = {'Items': []};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('browse subcategory');
    print(widget.subCategory);

        widget.subCategory.forEach((subcategory) {
          items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
        });
      print(items);
      print('sada');


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildCategoryHeading(context),
              GridView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.subCategory.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                  childAspectRatio: 4.0 / 7.0,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var category = categoryList[index];
                  double duration = index / 2;
                  return FadeInAnimation(
                    duration.toInt(),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          print(widget.subCategory[index]['Items']);
                          setState(() {
                            var items = {'Items': []};
                            print(items);
                          });


                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 80.0,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: 60.0,
                                height: 60.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .accentColor
                                          .withOpacity(.2)),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/icons/shirt.png'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                              Text(
                                widget.subCategory[index]['Name'],
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .subtitle2,
                              ).tr(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can see I am showing products that are coming in the Items array. Now what I need to do is onTap I need to clear all items. So after then ill insert another item so need to remove all arrays from Items.

Hope my question is understandable its simple mean I need to clear all arrays from Items when I click on GestureDetectore

Comment: is `items.clear()` is not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you clear list by tapping button, list will be added again when 'build' is called.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('browse subcategory');
    print(widget.subCategory);

        widget.subCategory.forEach((subcategory) {
          items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
        });
```

So you need to move initializing list code.

```
class _BrowserCategoryPage2State extends State<BrowserCategoryPage2> {
  var items = {'Items': []};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print(widget.subCategory);

    widget.subCategory.forEach((subcategory) {
       items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
    });     
    print(items);
    print('sada');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('browse subcategory');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildCategoryHeading(context),
              GridView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.subCategory.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                  childAspectRatio: 4.0 / 7.0,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var category = categoryList[index];
                  double duration = index / 2;
                  return FadeInAnimation(
                    duration.toInt(),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          print(widget.subCategory[index]['Items']);
                          setState(() {
                            items = {'Items': []};
                            // Or 
                            // items['Items'].clear();
                            print(items);
                          });


                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 80.0,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: 60.0,
                                height: 60.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .accentColor
                                          .withOpacity(.2)),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/icons/shirt.png'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                              Text(
                                widget.subCategory[index]['Name'],
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .subtitle2,
                              ).tr(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign a new value, that is empty:

```
items['Items'] = [];
```

You can also call the [clear](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/clear.html) method:

```
items['Items'].clear();
```

And if you want make the smallest possible change to your code that would work, remove the `var`, you don't want a *new* variable, you want to change the *existing* one:

```
setState(() {
   items = {'Items': []};
   print(items);
});
```

Comment: @rameezkhan Okay, so did you try it? Did it work?

Answer (score -2):

I have never used flutter but Id say just declare the array again.

```
var items = {'Items': []};

widget.subCategory.forEach((subcategory) {
  items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
});

//declare array again to empty array

var items = {'Items': []};
```

Comment: Please don't take guesses. It looks mostly correct, but we aim to be more than the site where you get a mostly correct guess.

Comment: @nvoigt I am experienced enough to be able to provide the above answer without having to use flutter, it's a very basic programming concept.

Comment: Well, you made the same mistake the OP did, so I guess it's not that easy. The mistake is not specific to flutter btw.

Comment: What are you referring to  ?

Comment: You cannot "declare" it again. You can remove the declaration part and it would work though.

Comment: You are referring to a mistake the OP published after I answered the question. I do not agree with you trying to silence people answering questions. I will continue to answer.

Comment: Your answer, as posted right now, would not work. Period. Has nothing to do with Flutter either. I don't try to "silence" you, I try to improve your answer. One way would be to fix your mistake. Please note that I have not yet voted on your answer.